# Calculation of accumulation area

Tags: c++, c, delphi, gis

I'm looking for a GIS/Geometric algorithm:

I have 1000 points randomly distributed in a large area(such as a city), How can I find out all the small areas which have more than 15 points? Like this picture below:

[image]

Each point has its own latitude and longitude coordinates. The small area less than 200m x 200m.

Comment: Which data structure do you use to manage your points?

Comment: All points are stored in db table.

Comment: Isn't there a select statement in the database that does this?

Comment: BTW very nice question. Love the clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should take a look at RTREE structures.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

You've such algorithms implemented e.g. in the SQlite3 engine.
See http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html

Our Open Source version already includes the RTREE extension for Delphi 6 up to XE, [compiled by default since rev. 1.8](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/07/22/Synopse-SQLite3-Framework-1.8).

Comment: You may further refine your Search (if applicable) by mixing different DS like K-D Tree and R-Tree, For e.g a 2-Dim R Tree. Such a DS will optimize your search time, and give you output based on defined bounding box. 

However for asserting the output item to a specific count such 15 in your case, you have to apply recursive searching logics...

Comment: To A.Bouchez and Nains: Sorry, I do not have the experience of R-Tree. Can you explain more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your performance requirements are. But a naive implementation would be, for each point, to sum up the inverse of the distance to all other points:

```
for i := 0 to 999 do
  for j := 0 to 999 do
    if i<>j then
      Point[i].Score := Point[i].Score + ( 1 / Distance(Point[i], Point[j]) );
```

The points near the center of each accumulation area will have the highest score.

Comment: The performance of such an algorithm is `O(n^2)`; Should be avoided for any significant number of points. For 1000 points this does the calculation 1 million times. For 10,000 points this does the calculation 100 million times!

Comment: I am fully aware of that. "Not sure what your performance requirements are" and "a naive implementation would be". 1 million calculations for 1000 points would still be doable in pretty reasonable time on a modern CPU and the Questioner stated that he got 1000 points. The advantage of this approach is that it is trivial to implement and might run at an acceptable performance (but that's something that only the Questioner could decide as he doesn't give us enough information to determine that).